# Where to store credentials and other secrets for Apache Flink SQL?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm doing a PoC for Flink SQL, and I'm wondering what the proper way is to deal with credentials, for example when accessing databases and Kafka. It obviously works when I include them in the query, but sprinkling credentials all through the query isn't great.

Can I refer to a secret contained in a mounted file? Or at least an environment variable?
Is there a ${ENV} or something?

For example, I would like to supply the credentials from elsewhere:

```
CREATE CATALOG analytics WITH (
    'type'='jdbc',
    'base-url'='jdbc:postgresql://some-postgres:5432/',
    'default-database'='analytics',
    'username'='someuser',
    'password'='somepassword'
);
```

Similar when creating Kafka tables.

I'm suppose that I can include an UDF that can do that, but before I go down that road I'd like to know if there is something obvious I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Credentials can be stored in `flink-conf.yaml`, and accessed as configuration parameters. Note that any configuration setting containing one of these strings

```
"password", "secret", "fs.azure.account.key", "apikey"
```

will have its value obscured in the logs.

You also have the option of defining tables in one of the catalogs supported by Flink SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass your credentials as arguments to your program. You can make a properties file to define whatever you want and pass it to your Flink program.

`val username = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args).getRequired("username")`

Comment: but I think credentials as arguments is not secured.